# frequency of connector/splitter for RG-6 cable internet connection

Tags: cable-modem, splitter

Moved into a new place, and the cable run under the house was split a bunch of different times. So I ran a new drop straight from the outlet I want to the box outside, it's for the internet and is the only connection I need. I didn't know there were different frequencies of connectors tho, so I'm not sure what to do. I was going to use a standard inline butt connector to join the two ends together (the cable from the provider to the cable I ran), it says it is 1ghz, but I see there are also 3 ghz ones, and what is in the box now is a grounded splitter that says 3-5 ghz

My questions, does it matter? Does using a splitter if you only use 1 of the spits still split the signal? Would I be better off with the 2-5ghz grounded splitter vs the 1ghz connector? Should I go buy a 3ghz inline connector?

Thanks for any help in clueing me in to what any of this means, it's much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An RG-6U connector is a full frequency bandwidth connector. If you can push it through the RG-6U cable, the connector isn't a concern. The other items are devices that will have bandwidth limitations.

If you are concerned for only internet service, any F-81 (dual female threaded) connector will do, as they are also not frequency or bandwidth limited (within reason, don't go shoving microwaves through it). The same applies to a ground block. Splitters will have frequency limitations.

Our local cable company sent a tech out to replace an amplifier. I was able to query him regarding the bandwidth of our full-service internet and cable television service. He informed me that it is no more than 1 GHz. In my early days of CATV, the bandwidth was 220 MHz (0.220 GHz). He also assured me that the RG-6U cable was capable of handling the entire bandwidth.

Additionally, your internet service is on the low frequency end of the bandwidth. You'll not find on the consumer market a device with as restrictive a frequency as that occupied by the incoming and return bands required for internet service.

1 GHZ is going to work fine for you.

Comment: awesome, thank you very much for that!